# Who was the first to state that scientific theories could be used to make predictions?

Tags: biographical-details, discoveries, astronomy, philosophy-of-science

It seems to me that very few if any scientists/philosophers stated that science could be used for predictions before the early 1900s. In the scientific context I have only encountered the use of the word prediction only in relation to astronomy.
I suppose this may be due to the few predictive theories outside astronomy back then

Comment: Are you asking when they actually spelled out the word "prediction"? Because Euclid predicted what reflections in a circular mirror would look like, Archimedes predicted when submerged bodies would float, Galileo predicted that projectiles would have the longest range when launched at 45°, etc.

Comment: @conifold Yes , I am asking of who firstly described theories as instruments that can potentially give predictions about the world.

Comment: This is too vague and smeared over centuries as a result. They were deciding what "theory" predicts and then staging experiments to see if that is so since they were [staging experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_experiments), even earlier in astronomy since no staging was required. Newton "describes" it for special cases in *Principia*, and he was not the first. But if you want it at the level of abstraction of the modern terminology in your post then it is likely mid-19th century when Whewell and others started writing treatises on "scientific method".

Comment: @conifold Can you provide some more specific quote? The fact that "this too vague and smeared over centuries" makes me wonder of how many procedures(that are now motivationally and conceptually unreachable)  of how we conduct science may be  concisely described in the future.

Comment: [Hooke writes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/230074) "*Now as the theory is very short, so the way of trying it is very easie...*", [Newton writes](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Mathematical_Principles_of_Natural_Philosophy_(1846)/Axioms,_or_Laws_of_Motion) "*Hitherto I have laid down such principles as have been received by mathematicians, and are confirmed by abundance of experiments... But to prevent an objection that may perhaps be alledged against the rule, for the proof of which this experiment was made...*". Does it count?

Comment: @conifold I meant a quote from the more modern philosophers like Whewell.

Comment: This is one of those questions that at its heart is [ahistorical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahistoricism), since continued minor tweaking what "scientific context" means will lead you back further and further. Surely [the prediction of eclipses by the Greeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_of_Thales) qualifies. What about even earlier predictions of planetary motion, the rise and fall of the Nile river a couple of thousand years before this, the prediction of sunrise/sunset times probably even earlier, etc.?

Comment: @Dave L Renfro I don't think that my question "is ahistorical" since explicit general philosophical description of scientific theories is a rather modern conception as conifold's last comment  implies.

Comment: "*It is a test of true theories not only to account for, but to 
predict phenomena*", Whewell, [The philosophy of the inductive sciences (1840)](https://archive.org/details/philosofindu01whewrich/page/n45/mode/2up). Plato called it "*saving the phenomena*" two millennia earlier. Although, characteristically, it was not his "theory" which "predicted" celestial bodies moving in perfect circles, but the phenomena, that required saving. [Duhem](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1997JHA....28....1G) took it to be what Ptolemy was doing in *Almagest*.

Comment: If you are performing an engineering task, than you do it because you want to make something, ie you have to predict the size, properties etc using your theory. While it may not have been spelled out this way by philosophers of the time, conscious engineering clearly  proves the intent of prediction using the given theories. Since engineering exists from ancient times, I think it is a good estimation for you.